# Setting background color in JavaFX not working

Tags: java, javafx, background-color, scene

I am trying to code a program that takes in user input in one scene to set the background color in the second scene. Everything works except the background does not change the color, it stays white. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

```
public class Project extends Application {

    Scene scene1, scene2;

    final int WIDTH = 600;
    final int HEIGHT = 600;

    Label labelLightOrDark;

    TextField tfLightOrDark;

    private GridPane createTextFieldPane() {
        GridPane gPane = new GridPane();
        labelLightOrDark = new Label("Is it light or dark? ");

        tfLightOrDark = new TextField();

        gPane.add(labelLightOrDark, 0, 2);
        gPane.add(tfLightOrDark, 1, 2);

        return gPane;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        //first scene
        Button btGenerate = new Button("Generate My Background!");

        GridPane gPane = createTextFieldPane();
        gPane.add(btGenerate, 0, 6);
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(gPane, 600, 600);

        //second scene
        Button btReturn = new Button("Try Again!");
        btReturn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event2) -> {
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);});

        Pane root = new Pane();
        String bColor = tfLightOrDark.getText();

        if (bColor.equalsIgnoreCase("light")) {
            root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightblue;");}
        else if (bColor.equalsIgnoreCase("dark")) {
            root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkblue;");}

        root.getChildren().add(btReturn);
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        btGenerate.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Create Your Own Background!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I believe the problem has to do with my if, else if statements because when I comment out these lines it does set the background of the second scene to light blue.

```
    //if (bColor.equalsIgnoreCase("light")) {
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightblue;");}
    //else if (bColor.equalsIgnoreCase("dark")) {
        //root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkblue;");}
```

Comment: Use a change listener on `tfLightOrDark` to do your `if-statement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is OK, but keep a ref to whats clicked. Here is the code.

```
    Scene scene1, scene2;

    final int WIDTH = 600;
    final int HEIGHT = 600;

    Label labelLightOrDark;

    TextField tfLightOrDark;


    private GridPane createTextFieldPane() {
        GridPane gPane = new GridPane();
        labelLightOrDark = new Label("Is it light or dark? ");

        tfLightOrDark = new TextField();

        gPane.add(labelLightOrDark, 0, 2);
        gPane.add(tfLightOrDark, 1, 2);

        return gPane;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        //first scene
        Button btGenerate = new Button("Generate My Background!");

        GridPane gPane = createTextFieldPane();
        gPane.add(btGenerate, 0, 6);
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(gPane, 600, 600);

        //second scene
        Button btReturn = new Button("Try Again!");
        btReturn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event2) -> {
            primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        });

        Pane root = new Pane();


        root.getChildren().add(btReturn);
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        btGenerate.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
            if (tfLightOrDark.getText().contains("light")) {
                root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightblue;");
            } 
            else if (tfLightOrDark.getText().contains("dark")) {
                root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkblue;");
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Create Your Own Background!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is you are checking for the value in the text field before the scenegraph is rendered. You need to move the if-else logic to button onAction.

```
btGenerate.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            String bColor = tfLightOrDark.getText();
            if (bColor.equalsIgnoreCase("light")) {
                root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightblue;");
            } else if (bColor.equalsIgnoreCase("dark")) {
                root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkblue;");
            }
            primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
        });
```